# Help with wiring up new bathroom exhaust fan

Tags: electrical, exhaust-fan

I removed an old Nutone bathroom fan from the ceiling. I'm installing a new Nutone fan. I can get the fan to blow when I connect the fan black and black hot wire, and fan white and white neutral wire from one of the two cables available (#1 in the photo). But it blows continuously (ignores the timer). What I can't figure out is how to get the timer working with the fan, and I suspect it's related to this other mystery cable up there (that's not live).
Any help is appreciated...![image: The wires I'm working with]

Comment: When you say "timer" you're referring to one that's mounted in a box on the wall, right?  Can you post photos of the inside of that box?

Comment: Does black 2 have voltage when the timer is on? (obviously, be careful when testing this as you'd need to work with live wires).

Comment: Daniel, no black 2 doesn't have voltage even when the timer is on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No big mystery. The cable that runs the fan is the power supply (unswitched) from the breaker box.

The other cable is a switch loop to your timer. It's even properly marked with black tape to show that it's a "white hot" for a switch loop and not, as you have mis-labeled it, "neutral 2"

*Write "all neutrals are white or gray but not all whites are neutrals" on the chalkboard 100 times.* (North-America-Specific)

Connect white-hot-2 to hot-black-1, white-neutral-1 (without any black wire attached - if you need more length, use white to extend it - using a proper splice connector, not twisting and taping) to fan neutral-white, and black-SWITCHED-hot-2 to fan hot-black.

And Next Time, and EVERY TIME AFTER THAT: Take. Pictures. Before. You. Disconnect. Any. Wires!

This is a very common configuration in work done before the adoption of NEC2011, and sometimes seen in later work by the misinformed. Plenty of bad websites still pushing the old version (as stolen from some book, typically) without any warning that it only applies to old work you might run into, not new work you'd be doing. After NEC2011 a /3 cable is needed for a switch loop, as neutral (on white) is to be supplied to the switch location, and then black is usually hot and red is usually switched hot. Any old house will have this, instead, though.